# Load information based on whether the user is logged in

Tags: visual-c#-express-2010

I'm making a log-in form where it will be compared to the database and the information that will be shown on the main form would be based on the user logged in.

I was thinking of using a variable that would be passed from the log-in form into the main form. can this solve my problem or is there another method that might seem to be more appropriate?

Comment: Have you solved this?

Comment: not exactly solved by the way i want it to be but i used my login form as a dialog

Comment: ok, just edit the question if you need more help

Comment: ill post my answers after im done

Comment: Have you found a suitable solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

Can this solve your problem? Yes.
However, it would be easier to check the database directly from the login form, then call the main form if the user has correct credentials.